# Решение дифференциальных уравнений в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Есть следующий код:

```
T=[0 5];
y0=0.5;
Y0=[0,y0];
odefun=@(x) (-1).*exp(x)./(exp(x)+1)
[x,y]=ode45(odefun,T,Y0)
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',2)
grid on
xlabel 'x'
ylabel 'y'
```

Из-за чего происходит следующая ошибка?

> error using odu Too many input arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за того, что у `odefun` должно быть два аргумента, время и вектор состояния:

```
odefun=@(t,x) (-1).*exp(x)./(exp(x)+1)
```